# Insert link in the royal slider image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

I made an image gallery using the royal slider but do not know how to put the images link.

Images are inserted in this way:

```
<a class="rsImg"  data-rsBigImg="../img/paintings/2.jpg" href="../img/paintings/700x500/2.jpg">Vincent van Gogh - The Starry Night<img width="96" height="72" class="rsTmb" src="../img/paintings/t/2.jpg" /></a>
```

The href is the source image.. How do I get link?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you clarify your question please.

Comment: For those who need too I just managed to solve my problem using this code: <a class="rsContent" href="example.com"><img src="../img/paintings/2.jpg" class="rsImg"/></a>

Comment: Diego Machado..is  not working

Comment: @RaviMane what are you trying to do?

Comment: Dear Diego Machado ....i just want to add link on image, which is first anchor tag. i even replaced first anchor tag with img tag, and placed anchor tag outside but couldn't work.